# Ubuntu 18 Huge Wifi issue | Question Sign | works once once doesn't

Tags: wireless

I'm new to the forum. However I'm not totally stranger to Ubuntu.

My Wifi behavior, is very non deterministic which means annoying.

I use laptop. Old e4300 with some broadcom card, What happens is:

i.e. I can be connected for two days without any issue, but soon I will notice a question sign on Wifi icon on taskbar. When it happens I cant even use IP address to reach my router. I can try to reconnect but it gives usually nothing.

Already tried : 
/etc/resolv.conf refresh/with google dns

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

fixed configuration and leased IP Address, with native router dns's and with those from Google.  Issue always comeback and is really difficult to get rid of. Depends on luck, after few network device resets or re-connection attempts.

Nothing seems to work. Does anyone had similar issue but managed to resolve it? Please I appreciate your support.

Best regards Piotr

Comment: Which "some broadcom card"? `sudo lshw -C network` will show you. `journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager)` will show you interesting log messages.

Comment: 0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Comment: https://textuploader.com/dbh3o Due to comments limitations here is tail 200 from Journal